# In a multi monitor setup does duplicating screens use up more resources of the GPU

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, gpu

I've connected both my monitor and my tv to my PC, i'm not extending the desktop, just outputting the same image to both monitors, does this take up resources or it's just the same as having one monitor?

Comment: see this: http://forums.overclockersclub.com/index.php?showtopic=189542

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty much identical to one monitor.  The GPU only needs to do calculations for the 1 area, and the amount of memory required is only for the 1 image, so the only difference would be a minute additional power draw.

Comment: I'm not so sure about that, because I know that you can have different resolutions on each monitor, even though you are mirroring. In the best scenario there is at last a resampling job going on behind that.

Comment: I'm using the same res on both monitors. It's just that i want to play games on the tv and use the monitor for the rest

Comment: What davidgo said, is what I get mostly too. the second screen by itself barely budges the GPU use meter.  but if that second screen has activly refreshing or displaying things on it, then it uses GPU.  The quantity it uses is relative to that same window refreshing on the single monitor.  I believe i read something about how the Windows method is to not refresh when not needing to refresh, to not work when there is no work to do.  One time I had a program that was using Loads of gpu on the second screen, cut into the game needs for sure.

Comment: I'd put to you if you have different resolutions then you are no longer mirroring them.  Most monitors have logic to upscale a lower resolution signal, so - at least in the cases I've seen, if the laptop screen is 1366 x 768, the monitor will upscale the 1366 x 768 to native resolution of 1680 x 1050 (or whatever it is).